# How can swap columns into rows and maintain its values using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a problem when working with a tabular data series in Pandas. In particular, I have a DataFrame with a structure like the following:

| date | H01 | H02 | ... | H24 | Variable | station_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D_1 | Value_101 | Value_102 | ... | Value_124 | Var_1 | Code_1 |
| D_1 | Value_201 | Value_202 | ... | Value_224 | Var_2 | Code_1 |
| D_2 | Value_301 | Value_302 | ... | Value_324 | Var_1 | Code_2 |
| D_2 | Value_401 | Value_402 | ... | Value_424 | Var_2 | Code_2 |

Note: Date is format like: 2022-09-01 (YYYY-MM-DD) and H01, H02, ..., H24 represents the 24-hours in a day.

And I would like to be able to convert it into something like:

| datetime | Var_1 | Var_2 | ... | Var_N | station_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D_1 + H01 | Value_101 | Value_201 | ... | Value_N01 | Code_1 |
| D_1 + H02 | Value_102 | Value_202 | ... | Value_N02 | Code_1 |
| D_1 + H03 | Value_103 | Value_203 | ... | Value_N03 | Code_1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| D_1 + H24 | Value_124 | Value_224 | ... | Value_N24 | Code_1 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| D_2 + H01 | Value_301 | Value_401 | ... | Value_N01 | Code_2 |
| D_2 + H02 | Value_302 | Value_402 | ... | Value_N02 | Code_2 |
| D_2 + H03 | Value_303 | Value_403 | ... | Value_N03 | Code_2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| D_2 + H24 | Value_324 | Value_424 | ... | Value_N24 | Code_2 |

Note that can be multiple timestamp repeated (can exist one timestamp per station_code). That is, I would have to combine the column 'datetime' + all the columns that have 'H01', 'H02', ..., 'H24' in an index, and the rest of the remaining columns should be the values (in particular, var column should take the column header of each value).

Do you know how to achieve that?

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: What is the exact format? Do you really have `H01`/`H02` etc?

Comment: Thank you so much! That link helps so so much for understanding pivot tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)/[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
out = (df
   .set_index(['date', 'Variable', 'station_code'])
   .rename_axis(columns='hour')
   .stack().unstack('Variable').reset_index()
   .assign(datetime=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d.pop('date'))
                             +pd.to_timedelta(d.pop('hour').str
                                               .extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
                                               .astype(int), unit='H')
          )
)
```

Output:

```
Variable station_code      Var_1      Var_2            datetime
0              Code_1  Value_101  Value_201 2023-01-01 01:00:00
1              Code_1  Value_102  Value_202 2023-01-01 02:00:00
2              Code_1  Value_124  Value_224 2023-01-02 00:00:00
3              Code_2  Value_301  Value_401 2023-01-02 01:00:00
4              Code_2  Value_302  Value_402 2023-01-02 02:00:00
5              Code_2  Value_324  Value_424 2023-01-03 00:00:00
```

Used input:

```
         date        H01        H02        H24 Variable station_code
0  2023-01-01  Value_101  Value_102  Value_124    Var_1       Code_1
1  2023-01-01  Value_201  Value_202  Value_224    Var_2       Code_1
2  2023-01-02  Value_301  Value_302  Value_324    Var_1       Code_2
3  2023-01-02  Value_401  Value_402  Value_424    Var_2       Code_2
```